# Inserting array item into JS object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have a unique situation that I'm struggling with. I have some data like this. Excuse any incorrect terms as I'm fairly new to this.

```
usersByName: {
    "tester": {
        0: {
            id: 123
            name: "Some Name"
            data: "Some data"
        },
        1: {
            id: 124
            name: "Some Name 2"
            data: "Some data 2"
        },
        2: {
            id: 125
            name: "Some Name 3"
            data: "Some data 4"
        },
    },
    "tester 2": {
        0: {
            id: 12
            name: "Some Name"
            data: "Some data"
        },
        1: {
            id: 13
            name: "Some Name 2"
            data: "Some data 2"
        },
    }
 }
```

I am returning a piece of data like this.

```
 {
      id: 44
      name: "Some Name New"
      data: "Some data New"
 }
```

and a name like `tester 2`.

How can I add the new piece of data to the name I have found so the new data gets added as a third element to `tester 2`.
I am using react and next js so hoping to add it directly to the state if possible.
I think something like this but can't work out the obvious parts of it that are wrong

```
this.setState((prevState) => ({
  usersByName: { // copy all other key-value pairs
    newuservar: {
      ...prevState.usersByName.newuservar, // copy all pizza key-value pairs
      X: newData,
    },
  },
}))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I see the user objects have the key start with numbers, I assume they're arrays. Try this:

```
// newuservar = 'tester 2';
this.setState((prevState) => ({
  usersByName: {
    ...prevState.usersByName,
    [newuservar]: prevState.usersByName[newuservar].concat(newData)
  },
}))
```